# Why isn't the UITextField refreshing every time I press the button?

Tags: objective-c, ios, uitextfield

I am performing the Pythagorean theorem, and every time you click the "calculate" button, it refreshes my `UITextField` with the answer.  And yes, it is a text field, not a label.  For some reason, it only refreshes once, and that is the first time I try it.  I tried setting it to `nil` first, but that didn't work.  Here is my function called when you press the button (After some debugging, I found it only is getting called once):

```
-(IBAction) calculate: (id) sender
{
    ansNum = (fabsf(fy * fy)) + (fabsf(fx * fx));
    ansNum = sqrtf(ansNum);

    [fField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",ansNum]];
}
```

Comment: How did you link up `fField` with the `UITextField`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So your `calculate` function is being ran when the relevant event triggers it, but running it again yields no results? Are either `fx` or `fy` changing so that different results should be present?

You could try put some debug statements in to try and work out what is going wrong, e.g.

```
- (IBAction)calculate: (id)sender
{
    ansNum = (fabsf(fy * fy)) + (fabsf(fx * fx));
    ansNum = sqrtf(ansNum);

    [fField setText:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%g",ansNum]];

    NSLog(@"%f, %f, %@", fx, fy, fField);
}
```

Comment: I tried that already.  It only prints the debug information once to the console.  Sorry, let me edit that in to the question.

Comment: How is calculate being invoked, through a PressUp event from a UIButton?

Comment: Touch down.  This is always how I've done it, does it have something to do with that?

Comment: I don't see why that would cause a problem. This might seem a bit strange but would it be possible to just create another UIButton and hook it up to calculate and see if that produced the same one-time-only result?